# Stop submitting form if user doesn't exist in Database

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am developing a code in JSP using Ajax to verify the user in DB (means there is one input box where user provides the email id then code checks whether user exists or not using ajax), if user doesn't exist on DB then user should not be able to submit the form. In below code, Ajax is working. It shows true/false according to returning from JSP user check file (user_exist_function.jsp) but I am not able to control to user to stop submitting if user doesn't exist on DB. Please help.

js

```
var MyApp = {};

function check() {
  xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject()
  var url = "user_exist_function.jsp";
  value = document.getElementById('email1').value;
  url = url + "?username=" + value;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true)
  xmlHttp.send(null)
}

function stateChanged() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
    var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = showdata;

    MyApp.status = showdata;

  }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  var xmlHttp = null;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function check_submit() {
  var var1 = MyApp.status.valueOf().toLocaleString();


  if (var1 == 'true') {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

html

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return check_submit();">
   Email Id: <input type="text" name="email" id="email1" onkeyup="check();">
   <font color="red">
     <div id="mydiv"></div>
   </font>
   <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

**user_exist_function.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@include file="Database_connectivity.jsp" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    try{
            String username = request.getParameter("username").toString();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT  * FROM V_USER_DATA WHERE " +
                    "EMAIL = ?");
            ps.setString(1,username);

            ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();


            if(res.next())
            {
                out.println("false");
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("true");
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            out.println(e);  
        }
%>
```

Comment: Here's the base functionality, simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1xdb3yzu/ Works fine, and so did your original code btw; I couldn't send the form. I recommend: a) using jQuery, b) proper indentation, c) variable names and value that are precise and straightforward

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input id="Mysubmit" type="submit"> 
   <span id="msgNotInDB" style="display:none">You are not in the database</span>


        if(res.next())
        {
            $("#Mysubmit").hide();
            $("#msgNotInDB").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Mysubmit").show();
            $("#msgNotInDB").hide();
        }
```

Note: this answer using jQuery, because any sensible attempt to use AJAX on a webpage would use jQuery (or at least a similar library).  What I showed can be done without it (using `document.getElementById()`) but there's really not much sense in it.

UPDATE:
I noticed that I put the jQuery code in the server-side code.  SO, let's expand our rewrite.  This should replace all of the given Javascript:

```
function check()
{ 
  $.get("user_exist_function.jsp", {username: $("email").val()},
    function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $("#Mysubmit").show();
            $("#msgNotInDB").hide();
        } else {
            $("#Mysubmit").hide();  
            $("#msgNotInDB").show();                    
        } );
```

}

Comment: Thanks James.. So do you mean that I need to replace the check function code with this check function code? and anyother library i need to include?